# #php - session if logout from user side admin side automatically logged out

Tags: php

If I am logged in at user side and admin side at the same time, when i click on logout button on user side it also logged out from admin side while both sides have it's on login and logout files.

### code of user side logout file

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('location:index.php');
?>
```

### code of admin side logout file

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('location:login.php');
?>
```

parent folder "reservation system" contain all user side file and child folder "admin" contain all admin side files.

Comment: you have to destroy user related session, not the entire session.

Comment: Don't call session_destroy(), just unset only those session variables which you are using on front side.

Comment: It is just because you have 1 user session for the website, so if you unset it, from the other place it won't exist, so you are logged out!

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `session_destroy();` here. `session_destroy()` deletes all session data associated with the current session. Check this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Use

```
unset($_SESSION["user_id"]);
unset($_SESSION["username"]);
```

Comment: @sameed Welcome. If your problem is solved then accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your logout destroys the session. Since the session is shared by your whole browser, all your tabs have the same session.

To avoid it so that you can log in/out with both kind of account without any issue, either use two different browsers (private navigation counts as a different browser) or log out by unseting the session variables that are specific to the kind of account you are logging out.